# How do I keep the values in my original list from changing

Tags: python, list

Im a little new to python, so this question may be very easy to answer. However, the logic doesnt make sense to me which is why I am posting this question. While there have been similar questions asked, they all used large chunks of code that were hard to read. Here is the program in python:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]

list2 = list1

for i in range(len(list2)):
    list2[i] += 1

print list1
```

When I run this program, it returns list1 as [2,3,4,5,6], which is identical to list2. My question is why list1 is connected to list2, and how to keep them independent of each other. Thank you for answering.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2612802/3001761

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `list2 = list1`, you are just passing the reference of `list1` to `list2` , you instead need to make copy of `list1` and pass that copy to `list2` .
Example -

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]

list2 = list1[:]

for i in range(len(list2)):
    list2[i] += 1

print list1
>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Or You can also use `copy` module -

```
>>> import copy
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> list2 = copy.copy(list1)
>>> for i in range(len(list2)):
...     list2[i] += 1
...
>>> list1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

If the list contains objects and you may want to copy them as well, in that case use [copy.deepcopy()](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html)

Answer (score 0):

By default assignment operator in python links the two objects, i.e. creates binding between the two objects.
in order for you to create a new independent object and still copy the original.
you would have to use copy ( shallow or deep , depending on your requirement )

```
list2 = copy.copy(list1)
```